# VM cannot access Windows 7 host website

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

Im developing a website using VS2008 on Windows 7. I am running a VM with IE6 on it and want to test that the site works ok on IE6. On the VM IE6 browser I type http://192.168.0.100/default.aspx since my router gave the windows host that ip address but the browser errors with : Cannot find server or DNS Error
I can ping the host though through a command window.

Could this be a firewall issue on Windows7 and how can I open it up to allow VM browsing of the host website?

Answer (score 0):

The most dangerouse but simplest way to test this theory:

Open the "Network and Sharing Center".  If you look at the left panel at the button there should be a "Windows Firewall" under the "See also" section.
On the left again there should now appear a "Turn Windows Firewall on or off"

So you can now quickly test and see if it is in fact your firewall blocking it.

I would not keep the firewall off, and would consider plugging out the network cable before I do this.

Hope it helps
Rihan